# How to switch home fragment between two different fragments depending on user's preference

Tags: android, fragment, fragmentmanager

I am in the midst adding a feature the my team's app that will allow the user to choose between 2 different home screens. Note that both of these screens have very different feels.

My current setup for this is to have 2 separate fragments Home1Fragment and Home2Fragment that both extend an abstract class called HomeFragment. The user will use Home1Fragment by default until they change the preference in the settings page.

I have both of these fragments implemented and both work properly if they act a lone as a home screen.

My problem resides when I try to switch them from one fragment to another. I've tried to this via

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

   if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 1) {
      fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();

      int option = getSharedPreferences('**hidden**', MODE_PRIVATE).get('home_screen_option', 0);
      Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.content);
      if(fragment != null && fragment instanceof HomeFragment) {
          if(f instanceof Home1Fragment && option == HOME_2) {
             f = new Home2Fragment();
          } else if (f instanceof Home2Fragment && option == HOME_1) {
             f = new Home1Fragment();
          }
      }
   } else {
      finish();
   }
}
```

*There may be typos in the code above because I wrote it on the fly without the real code in front of me.*

Comment: What's the problem with your code? the Fragment isn't shown?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually set the new fragment in your code.

But I would choose a different approach that's based on a saved state (e.g. a setting in shared preferences) and is handled by the home screen itself (instead of back stack manipulation which I advocate against).

Option 1.

Please think if your home screen can be a separate `Activity`. That way you can just load the correct fragment when the `Activity` starts based on a value stored in `SharedPreferences`.

Option 2.

Pretty much the same thing, just using a nested fragment. Let your home screen be a `Fragment` and add a container for child fragments in its layout. Then just use the child fragment manager to load the correct view accordingly.